# IHttpClientFactory and reading Cookies

Tags: .net, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I am accustomed to using `IHttpClientFactory` to create `HttpClient` for stateless Http requests. However, we now have a requirement to access a site and retain Cookies from that site's response. I am aware that [`HttpMessageHandler` are pooled and so `CookieContainer` cannot be relied upon for reading/writing Cookies with requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#cookies-2).

My question is: if using `IHttpClientFactory` to create an `HttpClient` then is a request's `HttpResponseMessage.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie")` reliable; or is this header affected by the Api's `HttpMessageHandler` pooling?